# microsoft oauth2 ( onbehalf of ) with background tasks

Tags: angular, api, flask, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I'm developing a flask + angular web app that uses Microsoft oauth2 (on behalf of user flow), everything works as wanted, but I need to add a feature to schedule some tasks monthly, that feature needs an OBO access token to Microsoft in order to perform that task, so how can I do that ? because the OBO access tokens that I'm getting in my web API are just useful for that moment not to schedule monthly tasks ! since my backend web API is stateless ? please any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

since your backend is stateless then I think you have to save the refresh_token to a database

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I think that this solution is not secure at all